# What is the specificity of the following selector table tr:first-child>span.class>a?

Tags: html, css

What is the specificity of the following selector : table tr:first-child>span.class>a?

Comment: What do you mean _what is the specificity_? That is the specificity .... do you mean how specific is amoungst all your other selectors? We would need to know what you are comparing it to.

Comment: https://specificity.keegan.st/

Answer (score 2):

Any [`a`] that is a **child** of any [`span` with the class `class`], which in turn is a **child** of a [`tr` that is the **first child** of its parent] that is a descendant of a [`table`].

It will target the only link in the example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Countries</th>
        <th>Capitals</th>
        <th>Population</th>
        <th><span class="class"><a href="#">Language</a></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>Washington D.C.</td>
        <td>309 million</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sweden</td>
        <td>Stockholm</td>
        <td>9 million</td>
        <td>Swedish</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There literally dozens of calculators online you could search for which will compute it for you: https://specificity.keegan.st/

Just copy and paste in your selector. It's `0,0,2,4`.